# Array of Objects vs Object containing Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

When do you decide to store a series of objects in an array vs storing the objects in an object?

Array of objects

```
[ {id:100, score:13}, {id:101, score:666} ]
```

Object of objects

```
{ 100:{id:100, score:13}, 101:{id:101, score:666} }
```

Comment: "Hash table" for example.

Comment: There are far too many potential answers here without some more details. There's a huge number of reasons you could choose one or the other.

Comment: Objects of Object makes sense to me when I have to keep relative info..for ex. `{ 'student' : { 'name': vishakha, 'DOB:' 4/10/1989, 'Roll': 100  }`

Answer (score 1):

essentially your question says when to store data as tuples(objects in array) and when to store data as hashMap(object against a key)

when you have lot of random key lookup then hashMap should be preferred because you dont have to traverse through all records in array to find a given key.

While when you have some analytics over data e.g sorting data according to some key in object then array of objects should be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to use them. In this instance, for example, you can use either. The array would indeed look like

```
[ {id:100, score:13}, {id:101, score:666} ]
```

But the object of objects can be designed as a key-value pair. So, something like this instead:

```
{ 100:{score:13}, 101:{score:666} }
```

Then you can access the `score` values directly, if you know the `id`, without having to check for `indexof` or going through the entire array/object.

Looping through the two structures would also be slightly different. For array of objects, you'd use `forEach`(or a `for` loop `0` to `array.length`), and for the object of objects you'd use `Object.keys`(or a `for-in` loop). It also boils down to specific scenarios, and you should be open to using either(I personally prefer object of objects).

Answer (score 0):

Part of it has to do with how you want to access, select, or cache a specific object later on.

```
var arr = [ {id: 100, score: 13}, {id:101, score:666} ];

console.log(arr[0]); //Object {id:100... etc.
```

The "array of objects" way can make it a little more tricky to figure out in which way you would like to access an element based on, say, it's 'id' property (and, if there's any easier way, someone please enlighten me):

```
function fn() {

    var myObj;

    arr.forEach(function(el,i,arr){
        if(arr[i].hasOwnProperty('id')) {
             if(arr[i].id == 100) {
             myObj = arr[i]; //myObj = {id:100, score:13}
          }
        }
    });

    //do something with myObj

}
```

Whereas with an object of objects, if you know you're trying to select the object with an 'id' property of 100:

```
var someObj = { 100:{id:100, score:13}, 101:{id:101, score:666} };

function fn() {
    var myObj;

    myObj = someObj[100]; //myObj = {id: 100, score:13}

    //do something with myObj
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on

- Your requirements.

  - Non functional requirements(data volume, operation frequency, data integrity requirement etc).
  - Functional requirements(What will you do to those data? insert or query? or transform?)
- Difference built-in attribute of hash map and array.(Performance, Memory usage etc)
- Difference of API and tools offered for hash map and array.
- Here, for Javascript, the requirements matters such as

  - Data volume
  - Which operation will be performed more, search or insert?(or another question, is most of the operations to the data read or write?)
- Here are some facts about data structure hash map and array,

  - Hash map is extremely fast for random key lookup(constant time)
  - Array is extremely fast for sequence element insert and loop over all elements (constant time)
- For APIs and Tools, general there's no big difference here since you can write code for both, but,

  - Javascript offers more element operation API for array, for example:

    - Filter some objects out of all the objects, you can use filter against all objects of an array very easily using Array.filter
    - You can also use Array.map to map current map to another one very easily using Array.map
    - Yo can refer here for more Array related APIs, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
  - While for object(hash map), most of the APIs javascript offered are related to Object operation, not the elements contained, through you can get all the contained objects and then perform operation on them, but that's not so connivence as Array, please refer here for detail, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object